# C++ Error I need help please?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, dev-c++, visual-c++-2010

I have done a code which has to be written a mathemathical function and then give the images. First, introduces the function as a string variable, but I don't know how to convert it in another type of variable to return the images of the function.

The compiler error I get is:

> cannot convert '`std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}`' to '`const char*`' for argument '`1`' to '`int printf(const char*, ...)`'

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cmath> 
#include<math.h> 
#include<vector> 
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<iomanip> //setprecision// 
#include<sstream> 
#include<string> 
#define precisio 4 
#define K 100   
using namespace std;  
double valors(double a, double b);  
double g(double x);  
double x; 
double a = x; 
double y(x); 
int i;    
int main () {       
  cout << setprecision(precisio);   
  cout << "Escriu l'interval de la funció" << endl;         
  double a, b;      
  cout << "\n a =";     cin >> a;       
  cout << "\n b =";     cin >> b;       
  cout << "Escriu la funcio" << endl;   string s;   
  cin >> s;     cout << s;      
  double y = printf(s.c_str());         
  valors(a,b); 
}  

double valors(double a, double b){          
  int punts = K*(b-a) + 1;      
  double amplada = (b-a)/K;         
  cout << "\n\tx\tf(x)" << endl;        

  for (int i = 0; i < punts; i++) {                 
    cout << "\t" << a << "\t" << g(a) << endl;      
    a = a + amplada;    
  }     
}

double g(double x){
   return y; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you performing this: `double y = printf(s.c_str());` when you could use `cout << s;` like you did in the lines above?

Comment: Using a debugger will help clarify issues.  This is a good example for learning to use a debugger.

Comment: This code compiles and runs without any editing. Whatever the problem is, it's either not in this code, or it's not what was asked.

Comment: No one else saw the missing return on valors()? O.o

Comment: @KostasLifeboy That seems to generate a warning more often than not.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
double valors(double a, double b)
```

Your function does not return any value, while it should return "double".

Comment: This is the only compilation error I've had, and only VS seems to treat it as an error.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with this online compiler utilizing C++14: [here](http://ideone.com/eQTbuy)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iomanip> //setprecision//
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#define precisio 4
#define K 100
using namespace std;
double valors(double a, double b);
double g(double x);
double x;
double a = x;
double y(x);
int i;
int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(precisio);
    cout << "Escriu l'interval de la funció" << endl;
    double a, b;
    cout << "\n a =";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\n b =";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Escriu la funcio" << endl;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s;
    double y = printf(s.c_str());
    valors(a, b);
}

double valors(double a, double b)
{
    int punts = K * (b - a) + 1;
    double amplada = (b - a) / K;
    cout << "\n\tx\tf(x)" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < punts; i++)
    {
        cout << "\t" << a << "\t" << g(a) << endl;
        a = a + amplada;
    }
}
double g(double x)
{
    return y;
}
```

Comment: LOL Youd didn't include <iostream> ;-;

Comment: @Kostas Lifeboy, it was there at IdeOne. It wasn't just in the code text here.

Comment: LOL I just tried it and it didn't throw any error O.o
Awesome! :D

Comment: Crank up the warning level. I use `-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the purpose of :

```
cin >> s;   cout << s;
double y = printf(s.c_str());
```

was to put the value entered by the user on standard input into y. If so, you should just do:

`cin >> y;`